# Where can I sell my illegal cargo?

Tags: rebel-galaxy

I'm sitting on a hefty stash of Narco-Cola now but I can't seem to find a station where I can sell it. I want to get rid of it as fast as I can in case I get scanned and lose it. Is my ability to sell certain types of cargo based on faction relations, have I not found the correct station yet or is there something else I need to do if I want to sell illegal cargo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you can trade these items depends on the Government's alignment; anarchist, totalitarian and theocractic governments will freely trade in illegal items.

There is a smugglers upgrade, although it only hides 4 contraband items. The rest will sit with the rest of your cargo.

Comment: There are also medium and large versions of the Smuggler hold, I usually buy them at Red Devil bases.

Comment: You can also sell illegal items to Traders/merchants that you find in space. Look for distress calls. Scratch their back and they will scratch yours. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can sell your illegal cargo in Juarez at the Loreto-Station at Black Market.[image: Map for Dodge-Sector - Juarez - Loreto-Station -Black Market]